# React Bootstrap Accordion scroll down on expanded content (scroll to where the space was created for the dropdown)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

excuse the poor image below but was wondering if it is possible? I tried using scrollTo and scrollToView with Refs and even added a delay timer to see if it would scroll after the accordion has been expanded/loaded but it couldn't work. I was wondering if it could be an css issue with the overflow and all but still couldnt figure it out.

```
handleBackClick = () => {
    this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: "nearest" })
}
```

I am using React Accordion Bootstrap Custom Toggle with Expansion Awareness.

[image]